# Reformat Date Argument in Contextual Filter

Tags: views

I have an argument in a view, contextual filter - {{ arguments.field_news_date_value }}. How can I reformat a date value from YYYY-MM-DD to DD Month Year in the view

Answer (score 0):

Select the custom format in the field's configuration and d m y there. Refer https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php to see php date format.